# Storing different density drawables in the folder

Tags: android, drawable

I have 2 doubts regarding storing the drawables in respective folders ie.. ldpi, mdpi..Which I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

1. I have folders like this:

[image]

Since I have all the possible folder names ie.., **ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi** should I delete the **default drawable folder**?

Or Should I move all the files from **drawable-mdpi** to the **default drawable folder** and delete the **drawable-mdpi folder**?

2. I am using few **xml** files as drawables, which are selectors, custom backgrounds etc.. Which contain the image references like

   ```
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vote_clicked" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vote_clicked" android:state_focused="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vote"/>
   ```

Where should I place these **xml** files? In every folder? Or the **default drawable folder**?

Anyways the pngs like `@drawable/ic_vote` are in every folder.

Comment: xmls go to the default folder. Images that are not tailored for each dimension go to the default folder, last resort fallback images go the the default folder (typically in case new selectors are added in the future)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything that is not DPI related should go in the drawables folder.

Anything else that is dpi related, should be in the relevant DPI folder.

There is no reason to delete any of the folders.

So your xml files should be in the drawable folder.

Also, it doesnt matter what folder they are in, you still reference them with `@drawable/` and it finds the right one.

Comment: `Anything that is not DPI related should go in the drawables folder` By that you mean the xml files?

Comment: So, I will keep all the drawables in respective folders plus mdpi images in the default folder(safe side). But the xml files are only in the default drawable folder.Right?

Comment: @AshMv Layouts should go in the layouts folder. Xml Drawables in the drawables folder.

Comment: @user1537779 That is right yes. mdpi images in mdpi folder, and xmls in drawables folder. Since the xmls are not DPI dependant. As for people saying it will error if no image is in the drawables folder, that is not true. It will resize an MDPI image to HDPI. Though it is recommended to have a hdpi image as well

Answer (score 2):

Android first checks for the resource in the corresponding density specific folder, example: ic_launcher.png for a medium density screen will first be searched in the drawable-mdpi folder. If found, well and good. In case, the image doesn't exist there, android picks from the drawable folder, the default.

hence, to have image resources specific to density, keep them in respective folders and a copy in the drawable folder as well [only for the safe side].

For the xml resources, keep them in the drawable folder only.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot. as per the `In case, the image doesn't exist there, android picks from the drawable folder, the default` what happens if the image is not present in the default folder also? Because once I missed an image in every folder except the `hdpi` but a medium device still picked that image.

Comment: @user1537779 `what happens if the image is not present in the default folder also` - android throws an exception

Answer (score 2):

I created five folders for drawable i.e. ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi. Also for layout i created three folder i.e layout, layout-large and layout-xlarge.
My project requirement was  Multiple Device Support. It worked well on all the devices.
Issue was with 10 inch and 7 inch tab. To solve this issue i created layout-large and layout-xlarge folders and place the respective files in respective folders. And now everything is working fine.
So its highly recommended that you create respective folder. Don't move everything to drawable or layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

Put the xml files in default drawable folder. Don't change others.

Answer (score 0):

You shound't delete any of this folders.

Drawable-density folders are using in all element which you want to add i.e. png files. In drawable folder you can add universal graphics, specified i.e. using XML structure (selectors etc.)